# Android error: null ponter exception to an include

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following

**main.xml:**

```
...
 <include
                    android:id="@+id/msg"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3.5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    layout="@layout/view_msg" />
..
```

**view_msg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view_img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" >
        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayouttest"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relLayouttess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="22dip"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtViewtess"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="234"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main.java** //extends Activity{
..

```
Test.setImageButton(this,
                R.id.msg,
                R.drawable.tess, Test.TAG_MESSAGES,
                mOnDialerClick);
```

**Test.java** //is a simple java class

```
public static  void setImageButton(Activity parent, int viewId,
            int imageId, int tag, View.OnClickListener listener) {

        View view = parent.findViewById(viewId);
        view.setTag(tag);
        view.setOnClickListener(listener);
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_img)).setImageResource(imageId);

        RelativeLayout relLayouttess =((RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.relLayouttess));

        TextView txtViewtess = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewtess));

        relLayouttess
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redbackground);
                txtViewNotifications.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

Both **relLayouttess** and **txtViewtess** are **NULL**. Why? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your code was incomplete for understanding the correct flow. Did you added the setContentView(R.layout.main) as 2nd statement before using this component?

Comment: The Main class does contain R.layout.main, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to look for `R.id.msg`. You can look directly for `R.id.relLayoutIcon` .

```
View view = parent.findViewById(viewId);
```

where viewId is `R.id.relLayoutIcon`

Comment: parent is the same activity that has as view hierarchy R.layout.main?

Comment: How can I refresh some static values from Test.java inside Main.java? Is it possible?

Comment: AFA is public static you can simply assign the new value